# Laravel exclude route

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this in my web.php (Laravel 5.3)

```
 Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'HotelsController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)'])->where(['seccion' => '(mis-hoteles|my-properties)']);
 Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'PerfilController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)']);
```

I want the urls `/perfil/mis-hoteles` and `/profile/my-properties` to be served by the first route. And the urls `/perfil/[whatever]` and `/profile/[whatever]` to be served by the second route.

It does not work, `/perfil/mis-hoteles` is redirected by the second route.

I'd also tried something like

```
Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'PerfilController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)','seccion' => '^(!mis\-hoteles$)'])
```

for the second route, but it does not work .

What am I doing wrong? 
The weird thing is, if I delete the second route and leave only

```
 Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'HotelsController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)'])->where(['seccion' => '(mis-hoteles|my-properties)']);
```

it works, so there is a match. Why if there is a match laravel continues looking for a match finding the second route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel does not like it when your routes have the same **method** and **uri sring**. If you have two routes with same **methods** and **uri strings** (not the actual uris they WILL receive) which you do, it just overrides it.

So we need to *"trick"* it a bit.

Instead of this:

```
Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'HotelsController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)'])->where(['seccion' => '(mis-hoteles|my-properties)']);
Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'PerfilController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)']);
```

We are going to *"lie"* and say:

```
Route::get('/{perfil}/{seccion}', 'HotelsController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)'])->where(['seccion' => '(mis-hoteles|my-properties)']);
Route::get('/{perfil}/{section}', 'PerfilController@index')->where(['perfil' => '(perfil|profile)']);
```

Notice the `{perfil}/{seccion}` and `{perfil}/{section}` just this one letter will tell Laravel that we don't want to override the old route.

> Don't forget to change the accepted parameter in the Controllers respectively.

Hope this solves your problem, it did for me.